# Streamlit Tornado vulnerability

Tags: tornado, streamlit

Apparently Tornado is vulnerable to proxy cache poisoning.

Would that mitigate it if I disabled cache setting in the Streamlit config file? If not is there is a way to avoid any risk from that vulnerability? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is actually found in the python standard library, not in Tornado itself. It is fixed in Python 3.6.13, 3.7.10, 3.8.8, and 3.9.2 (or higher versions in each branch).

[CVE-2021-23336](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-23336) for Python is replacing CVE-2020-28476 for Tornado according to [this comment](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2981#issuecomment-779183779) by the researcher who discovered the issue.